# Lazyload : Sidebar image not loading until full page scroll

Tags: jquery, jquery-lazyload

I have implemented [lazyload](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload) on my website, but i found that sidebar image is not loading until full page scroll. Because sidebar HTML code is footer and CSS is used to display that in sidebar.

Is there a way i can do something to show sidebar image without full scroll, for example after a little scroll

Test page : http://www.pricingindia.in/mobile/nokia-lumia-1320-price-80950

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bind the plugin separately to main content and sidebar. Something like:

```
$("#ProductPrice img.lazy").lazyload({
    effect: "fadeIn"
});

$("ul.listview img.lazy").lazyload({
    effect: "fadeIn"
});
```